# Organizing HTML and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that it is a good practice to organize files by separating them into files. i.e, files.html and files.js . However, I have lately been looking at some websites and the way their files are organized. They tend to contain tiny bits of JavaScript inserted here and there inside the html file.

Now, these files tend to be organized in a very particular way, one thing I have noticed is how I don't see much of `document.getElementById(id)` or ids. So, I am curious to know what is the best way to grab the elements using JavaScript. Should I grab the elements in the html file or in the JavaScript file, and how?

For instance take as an example the when a question is posted in Stack Overflow. Similar results are shown. What would the JavaScript would look like if I have something like the following:

```js
/* 
  SOMETHING LIKE THIS
  but this would mean that I would have to grab the elements everytime 
  the event is fired (not sure this is a good idea)
 */
var question;
var similar_question;
var ask_your_question;
var maybe_already_answered;

 Questions.checkSimilarQuestions = function(){
     question = document.getElementById('question');
     similar_questions = document.getElementById('similar');
   
     ask_your_question = document.getElementById('aks-your-question');
     maybe_already_answered = document.getElementById('maybe-already-answered');
 }

/* 
  OR MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE THIS 
*/
(function(){
     var question = document.getElementById('question');
     var similar_questions = document.getElementById('similar');
   
     var ask_your_question = document.getElementById('aks-your-question');
     var maybe_already_answered = document.getElementById('maybe-already-answered');
    /*
      Grab the rest of the elements and do something with them
    */
  
  
}())
```

```html
<div id='ask-your-question'>
<input type='text' id='question'/>
<div id='maybe-already-answered'>
</div>
</div>

<div id='similar-questions'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give this a try, but feel free to correct me.

The above example shows 2 different things Object Orientated JavaScript and Functional JavaScript.

A lot of inline JavaScript code is actually not inline in the static version of a web page but is either added by the server and / or a main JavaScript file.

Another reason you may not see `document.getElementById()` is because a lot, and I mean almost everybody, uses jQuery which uses a different Syntax. As far as I know there is no other way to fetch elements than document.getElement (id, class, tagname) with vanilla JavaScript. A jQuery declaration would look like

```
$('#wrapper');
```

**Best Practice?**

Well. I tend to declare elements I am going to be using as global variables. I can imagine that a lot of developers do this since it's easier to write

`searchForm.appendChild(someElement);`

than

```
document.getElementById('#search-form').appendChild(someElement);
```

Every single time.

I hope this gave you some insight as to best practice's :)

JSON example:

```
var elements = {
    body: document.getElementsByTagname('body')[0],
    wrapper: document.getElementById('wraper')};
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I think I forgot to mention jQuery. I don't see as much of jQuery('selector') either. I guess it is because of what you said ... put it into variable. But where do I put this variables, in an object or in plain single variable?

Comment: As a sidenote, document.querySelector() and document.querySelectorAll() can be used in vanilla javascript to select nodes using jquery selector syntax.

Comment: No problem. That depends on your preference. But even if you like functional JS more, like I do, I would still add all the elements in a globally declared notation styled object (JSON). This makes your code cleaner and easier to read for future development. It also means if you change something on the webpage you will only have to change it once. Personally I try not to use jQuery since it is a lot slower and over complicates something that is relatively simple.

Comment: @Shilly Yes. Forgot about that.

Comment: @Niels I prefer plain JavaScript. If it is not too much to ask for, would you be able to show me what it would look like in a globally declared notation styled object (JSON) ?

Comment: @Gacci I hope this helps you. You can declare them in a global anonymous function if you like.

Comment: @Gacci I made a mistake before but I've corrected it. Apologies.